# PHP- Remove keys from invalid json

Tags: php, json

I am new to php and dont know how to deal with invalid json.
So I want to remove those keys which have invalid string values

Here `tag_list` and `description` have invalid string values.

```
$json='{
    "kind": "track",
    "id": 132453675,
    "created_at": "2014/02/01 02:01:11 +0000",
    "user_id": 895073,
    "duration": 323242,
    "commentable": true,
    "state": "finished",
    "original_content_size": 7745028,
    "last_modified": "2014/02/23 15:48:45 +0000",
    "sharing": "public",
    "tag_list": "hi " how are",
    "permalink": "leaman",
    "streamable": true,
    "embeddable_by": "all",
    "downloadable": false,
    "purchase_url": null,
    "label_id": null,
    "purchase_title": null,
    "genre": "Pop",
    "title": "Leaman",
    "description": "what"" is for",
    "label_name": null,
    "release": null,
    "track_type": null,
    "key_signature": null,
    "isrc": null,
    "video_url": null,
    "bpm": null,
    "release_year": null,
    "release_month": null,
    "release_day": null,
    "original_format": "mp3",
    "license": "all-rights-reserved",
    "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/132453675",
    "user": {
        "id": 895073,
        "kind": "user",
        "permalink": "cloudsareghosts",
        "username": "cloudsareghosts",
        "last_modified": "2014/02/13 22:16:09 +0000",
        "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/895073",
        "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/cloudsareghosts",
        "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000005407842-c7dt3c-large.jpg"
    },
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/cloudsareghosts/leaman",
    "artwork_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000069579796-mhc0bg-large.jpg",
    "waveform_url": "https://w1.sndcdn.com/r4xyDo8zqpfU_m.png",
    "stream_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/132453675/stream",
    "playback_count": 253,
    "download_count": 0,
    "favoritings_count": 4,
    "comment_count": 0,
    "attachments_uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/132453675/attachments",
    "policy": "ALLOW"
}';
```

So how can I remove these keys `tag_list` and `description` from this json in php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the double quotes messes up the JSON. You would have to replace these `"` with `\"`

So:
 `"description": "what"" is for",`
should be
 `"description": "what\"\" is for",`

Depending on how you get the JSON, you could `str_replace` this with PHP instead of doing it manually.
For example, if this JSON is created by a script of your own, you could edit that to make sure it outputs the backward slashes with it. (Looping of the object and relacing double quotes in the values by `\"`.)

**EDIT:**
Example in PHP:

```
$json = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^([^"]*"[^*]+": )"(.*?)"(.*)$/mU',
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1].'"'.str_replace('"', '\"', $matches[2]).'"'.$matches[3];
    },
    $json);
```

This `preg_replace_callback` replaces the double quotes inside value declarations to `\"`. See it here: https://eval.in/294426

Comment: this json coming from api so how can I modify these string values as you told

Comment: can you demonstrate it with my json in question. how?/

Comment: I added a example code (PHP) to replace the double quotes around the values to single quotes.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I edited the example to use preg_replace_callback

Comment: I also added a link to a example, hope it helps

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work yet? The code in the example link show it processes the string correctly to a standard (JSON) object. After that, you can remove specific properties with this line of code:
 `unset($json->the_property_you_want_to_delete);`